# MariaDB not starting after a server restart

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, mysql, php-fpm, mariadb

I'm running a LEMP stack for my websites and they were running fine. Monitoring showed that the server wasn't responding to the pings, I restarted it. Now MariaDB service isn't running, my websites show "***Error establishing a database connection***".

**Sudo service mariadb start** gives the following error:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Results from ***systemctl status mariadb.service***:

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.4.32 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Thu 2023-12-28 00:05:15 PKT; 212ms ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 135599 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 135604 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 135612 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-envir>
    Process: 135752 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
   Main PID: 135752 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
```

and ***journalctl -xe***:

```
-- The job identifier is 8.
Dec 27 23:21:09 vps.example.com systemd[8592]: Listening on debconf communication socket.
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 10.
Dec 27 23:21:09 vps.example.com systemd[8592]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 7.
Dec 27 23:21:09 vps.example.com systemd[8592]: Reached target Sockets.
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 3.
Dec 27 23:21:09 vps.example.com systemd[8592]: Reached target Basic System.
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 2.
Dec 27 23:21:09 vps.example.com systemd[8592]: Reached target Main User Target.
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 1.
Dec 27 23:21:09 vps.example.com systemd[8592]: Startup finished in 119ms.
-- Subject: User manager start-up is now complete
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The user manager instance for user 1000 has been started. All services queued
-- for starting have been started. Note that other services might still be starting
-- up or be started at any later time.
--
-- Startup of the manager took 119349 microseconds.
Dec 27 23:21:53 vps.example.com polkit-agent-helper-1[9548]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty= ruser=alex rhost=  user=alex
Dec 27 23:22:19 vps.example.com polkit-agent-helper-1[10365]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty= ruser=alex rhost=  user=alex
```

`sudo service --status-all` command doesn't show MariDB in the services list.

I tried to restart nginx, PHP and even server and the problem persists. I couldn't understand the root cause for this.

Comment: could you check the logs file the error output that will provide further details for the root cause.

Comment: Just a note, this systemd unit file looks ancient.

Comment: What happens when you do `systemctl start mariadb`. And then ideally have another window open with `journalctl -f`